# Posts vs. Pages

Tags: posts, themes, pages, customization, comments

Okay so I've spent the last few weeks (on my spare time outside of work) creating a site for a client with a custom built theme. This is my first use of wordpress and the site can be seen here at http://portwashingtonmama.com
I have a bunch of different static pages. For example, if you go to the first page in the nav titled "Outdoor Fun" you can see that there is one long list of places for parents to bring their kids for outdoor activities. They are separated into 3 different categories "Local" "pretty Close" and "farther away." In each category, there are a number of venues.
My client informed me earlier this week that she wanted the user to submit venues via comments. Okay, so I enabled comments on each page. Now, she has requested that the user be able to comment on each separate VENUE on the page. i.e. a user can comment on "Bar Beach" and then "Blumenfield Family Park."
Can someone help explain my options here? I understand that I can re-do each and every page and instead of static info, I can make each venue a post, carefully inputting them in reverse order. But if I do this, can I still have the category titles "Local" "pretty close" and "farther away?" Or is there another option that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your "local" "pretty close" and "further away" is only title text on the page and is not actually linking somewhere. You can simply make each venue into a post and under "local" "pretty close" and "further away", add a link to the post after their description/introductions. This way they retain their category titles and users can comment separately.

Comment: that's right, they are just plain text styled with h3 tags. So if i were to go about making it this way, i would have my page "outdoor fun" have my title "local" and i would have to just list LINKS, I can't display the full "post" of each venue underneath?

Comment: Im saying to put a link to the full post under each venue. That way people can click the link to comment. Make a pst for each venue and on the listings page, add a link to the full post under each one.

Comment: i'm sorry, I don't know if I'm understanding correctly. so basically, i should leave the page as is, create a new post duplicating the info, and add a link to the post on the page I have now, correct? That way they can comment after clicking on the post?

Comment: @Kaitie - Exactly. Seems like a lot of work but thankfully all you have to do is copy the info. Do whatever it takes to make your client happy.

Comment: yes, i knew it was going to be a lot of work no matter what. this seems like a good alternative though, i was worried about turing the whole pages into chronological-ized posts. so thank you very much! :)

Comment: You're very welcome. And hey, in the future, always make separate posts for things like that. O_O

Comment: A final idea is this: On the page where you have all venues, perhaps you should cut some of the info off and add a "read more" link to the whole post. That way, readers are kind of forced to go to the main venue page.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a Page in Posts plugin. Each one has different results, so test on one page before going with a particular plugin. That will allow you to simply select a category or particular posts to insert into your post. I use this sort of functionality on my Bibliography pages, e.g. http://lianamir.com/vardin. I'm using Posts in Page, Version 1.0.9 | By IvyCat Web Services.